Converting tile backsplash to painted wall (old home)
I have a 100 year old brick craftsman home and the one kitchen wall is an exterior wall with no studs, just masonry.  The other wall is interior plaster and lathe.  When I removed the subway tile on both sides part of the wall came off in certain spots.
Please forgive my ignorance on this topic as I've only worked with newer construction materials previously.  What I'm seeing appears like a layer of 1/8" - 3/16" drywall mud on top of a more porous concrete or mortar like layer.  For example, this is the brick exterior wall side:


Then on the other side we have the stud wall with lathe and what appears to be some kind of similar two-texture layering on top (this side I have not scraped the quickset or the loose pieces of the top layer off of yet):

Originally my wife wanted to put a different tile back up so I wasn't thinking the surface had to be too perfect.  But now seeing the old tile removed she is asking for a simple smooth painted wall.  To achieve that, can I put drywall mud (the kind you mix from powder) on top of this surface and just float it out to be flat (ish) and then prime/paint?  Or do I need some kind of special masonry primer to prepare this porous surface first? I have tried to remove all the top layer which felt loose and in total I'd say that's 20% of the wall (mentioning that in case the recommendation is that I should consider removing it all).  The other 80% looks like it could be painted directly with some light sanding.
Thank you!

The surface looks like concrete.  Can you put an arm though that hole and guess what the thickness is?  Thick will be concrete, thin might just be a covering/mortar.

That wood you see at the bottom of the hole is the lathe.  I just broke a piece of the mortar/concrete off and it's about 3/16" thick.  On the other side, with the exterior brick, I'm not sure how thick it is since there is no area that goes all the way through.  But on the lathe side would they have put a more coarse mortar layer over the lathe first and then a finer plaster layer over there?

If you can get the wall decently flat, then gluing 1/4 inch drywall over it might be easier than drywall mud/plaster.  Paint does show minor imperfections in different light.  Mud/plaster almost need master work to not show over a whole wall.  One reason texture walls became a thing.

Thanks for the input.  One thing in my favor is there isn't a perfect wall in the house so the bar isn't "too" high.  That said I have some experience in iterating through the layers of mud to get a decent finish.  The main thing I was concerned about this time is mud going on top of this sandy/grainy mortar or concrete or whatever it is.  I just don't want the mud to fall off in chunks down the road because it didn't adhere to this surface.  I brushed it and shop-vac'd it but it's like the more you rub it the more grains/sand come off of it.

That's plaster.  I agree with crip659 here—if you can skim the wall close to flat, you can put up some drywall, which is much easier to deal with than plaster.

The main issue with adding another full layer (even a thin one) here is then there will be a step down to the non-backsplash wall which is currently coplanar.  I started with some quick-set lite last night and I'm just going to see how it goes I guess.  Worst case scenario if it becomes unworkable as a painted wall I'll just put bead board or tile over it.

It all depends on what you and your SO is happy with.  A bit of sun or a light hitting a painted surface can show imperfections.  Might just be for a half an hour a day and some people will not be bother.  Other people will be tearing out their hair.
